# Is it possible to send an SMS in iphone os 4 after the app has been "closed"

Tags: iphone, sms, ios4

In other words does the ability run background services to "finish your tasks" include sending sms.

Comment: If you are a registered Apple Developer, you should ask this question in their dev. forums, as iPhone OS 4.0 is classified. In other wordds, no one are allowed to discuss the 4.0 framework, other than at developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 1):

no it's not possible to send in background , because iphone will not allow you to do that as SMS must require user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Using the core telephony framework in the background is the same as any other framework. If this framework allows you to send SMSs from your app, it will do so in the background as well.